# Run text file as commands in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, command

If I have a text file with a separate command on each line how would I make terminal run each line as a command? I just don't want to have to copy and paste 1 line at a time. It doesn't HAVE to be a text file... It can be any kind of file that will work.

`example.txt`:

```
sudo command 1
sudo command 2
sudo command 3
```

Comment: A script is a text file, and a text file *is* a script.

Comment: I dislike when someone throws the book at peeps, let it go..

Answer (score 109, accepted):

you can make a shell script with those commands, and then `chmod +x <scriptname.sh>`, and then just run it by

```
./scriptname.sh
```

Its very simple to write a bash script

Mockup sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo command1
sudo command2 
.
.
.
sudo commandn
```

Comment: In linux extensions are not mandatory (you can even create a file with no extensions). It works even if extension is .txt

Comment: Yes, but you should have this "#!/bin/sh" at the head of your file so that the kernel knows that its a shell script

Comment: You do NOT! need to edit the file, nor do you need `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the file!  You just need to do what `kclair` sez to do: `sh your_file_here_and_it_can_have_any_random_filename`.

Comment: You don't have to change the extension, nor add shebang at the top. If you make it executable `chmod +x example.txt` the shell executes a command equivalent to having a shell invoked with the pathname as its first operand.

Answer (score 93):

You can also just run it with a shell, for example:

```
bash example.txt

sh example.txt
```

Comment: also to debug it you can use bash -x example.txt

Answer (score 34):

Execute

```
. example.txt
```

That does exactly what you ask for, without setting an executable flag on the file or running an extra bash instance.

For a detailed explanation see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like this:

```
for i in `cat foo.txt`
do
    sudo $i
done
```

Though if the commands have arguments (i.e. there is whitespace in the lines) you may have to monkey around with that a bit to protect the whitepace so that the whole string is seen by `sudo` as a command.  But it gives you an idea on how to start.

Comment: This is terrible advice if `foo.txt` contains more than one token on any line.  You're much better off with `sudo -s <foo.txt` if indeed you need `sudo` for each command in the script. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: I liked your ans just to run particular line e.g. 3rd can do like
sed '3q;d' foo.txt | bash

Answer (score 6):

```
cat /path/* | bash
```

OR

```
cat commands.txt | bash
```

Comment: No need for an extra process, if you want to provide `bash` with the input use redirection