# Run bash commands from txt file

Tags: linux, file, bash

I have some commands in txt file and I need to execute all them line by line. How could I do it?

Comment: How about `bash file.txt`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ubuntu run text file as command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825495/ubuntu-run-text-file-as-command)

Comment: You may also have to convert it to UNIX format with `dos2unix file.txt`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Just do `bash file`:

```
$ cat file 
date
echo '12*12' | bc

$ bash file
Mon Nov 26 15:34:00 GMT 2012
144
```

In case of aliases just run `bash -i file`

*No need to worry about file extensions or execution rights.*

Comment: This works with native commands but I have an *alias* stored in my file and this way not working. I got error: "No command 'mycm' found ...". Are there another way for it?

Comment: @HankPhung `bash -i file`

Answer (score 28):

In a Terminal just type:

```
bash path/to/my/file.txt
```

And you will get each lines executed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `bash <file>` mentioned above, `source <file>` will also work. It's almost the same, except the commands are executed in the same shell, and so any side effects in the script will persist in the current shell; details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it).

Answer (score -3):

just change the extension of the file to .sh

add /bin/bash at starting of the file

change the permission of the file to executable

than simply run ./filename.sh command in command line.  all the commands in the file will be executed

Comment: If who made the question doesn't how to execute commands stored in a file, I doubt he will able to rename or change permission without any extra explanation.

Comment: If he needs executing command, then obviously he knows something about the commnadline(though I don't expect he knows very mush about shell). I think working in shell is a immense beauty and nice. I told him about the very basics of shell programming. In stackoverflow, some coding is always been wellcomed. Then If I say him about the coding in shell, then what is wrong?? and why the dwnvote?

Answer (score -6):

Change the extension to .sh and for the first line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and as someone else said `chmod +x`

Comment: Changing the extension is not important nor relevant.