# Give multiple terminal commands in a single file and run all the commands at once?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm a beginner into Raspberry pi and i have a basic doubt.

I'm basically trying to make my raspberry pi into a beacon and advertise data from it to a Android app.

I wonder if I can give multiple terminal commands in a single file and run all the commands simply by compiling and running the file?

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview).

My basic doubt is that, each time i have to check if a device is available(bluetooth) and advertise it, it takes a command for each of this. Can i integrate multiple raspberry pi commands into a file and run all these commands simply by compiling and running the file (as a script)?

Few of the commands are as follows :

```
sudo hcitool lescan, 
sudo hcitool hci0,
sudo hcitool -i hci0 0x008,
```

and few commands like these..

Comment: You'll repay the time you spend reading a Scripting tutorial. This looks pretty good : http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file `example.txt` with your commands:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
sudo hcitool hci0
sudo hcitool -i hci0 0x008
```

Then you can execute those commands by running `sh example.txt` or `bash example.txt`.
See [ubuntu run text file as command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825495/ubuntu-run-text-file-as-command)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to use python for this you could use the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
with open ('/home/pi/bluetoothcommands.txt') as btcommands:
    for line in btcommands:
        subprocess.run (line)
```

If you wanted this in a loop:

```
import subprocess
with open ('/home/pi/bluetoothcommands.txt') as btcommands:
    while True:
        for line in btcommands:
            subprocess.run (line)
```

In the /home/pi/bluetoothcommands.txt file:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
sudo hcitool hci0
sudo hcitool -i hci0 0x008
```